# Wget using domain name from within server - how to reduce DNS lookups?

Tags: dns, wget

I have a requirement to use wget command from within the hosting **server** to download a bunch of html files to a particular folder. I am placing the urls to download in a text file and using -i (input file) flag of wget. The urls are of the form https://.com/page1.php,https://.com/page2.php and so on.

In such case, I believe there will be dns resolution for each and every request. Is there a way to optimize the dns lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need anything else. Wget internally caches the DNS responses within a single run. So after the first request, it will not send any more DNS queries but will instead directly use the IP addresses found in the response.

In general, if you'd like to do this, you should install a DNS caching service like pdnsd on your server